# jQuery: mouseout not triggering if mouse is moved out too fast?

Tags: jquery

```
$(".np-button").mouseover(function() { 
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});
$(".login-button").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev().show();
});
```

The first button hides itself and shows the second button in the same place. All good.

However, if I quickly mousover and mouseexit the first button, the second button will stay active (the mouseout event related to the second button won't be triggered).

How can I fix this?

Edit: here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aArub/ . Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you could give us a full example, with html and javascript.  Preferably, recreated in a sandbox like http://jsfiddle.net  This way we can actually see what is going on.  It may be related to something else on the page or another piece of javascript.

Comment: I've found `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` to be far more predictable.

Comment: Mouseenter triggers only once, as well as mouseleave, mouseover on other hand triggers everytime u put the mouse over it and move it even if you have not left the element .

Comment: The question is properly formulated, has relevant code and clear description of the issue. The only thing it is missing is a jsFiddle. That alone causes 3 down votes and 2 close votes (as of now) !!!

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aArub/ . Try to move quickly over "NamePrice" - it will show "Login", and won't trigger the login mousout.

Comment: @amit:  I didn't vote the question down.  I just wanted some html to go with the JS.  Sometimes the problems lie where we don't expect.

Comment: That comment was not for any specific user as I don't even know who voted him down or who voted to close. I was just wondering why so when there are much worse written (and simpler) questions that get multiple answers without any down votes.

Comment: I am sorry, but mouseenter and mouseleave (at least in version onmouseenter= "function1" onmouseleave="function2") does not work, either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I see a couple of possible issues.

The first issue I see is that `Login` is a shorter element than `Name Price`.  This means that if you hover over the end of `Name Price`, like on the `e` for instance, you trigger mouseover/mouseenter on `Name Price`, but you don't end up on top of `Login`.  If you move away at this point, you will never trigger a mouseout/mouseleave event.

Secondly, when you move through the button quickly, there is some tiny delay for the javascript to respond (we are in real life after all, computers do take some time to process information).  This means that when you enter the button, it will *begin* to hide `np-button` and show `login-button`.  When you move quickly, **the mouse leaves `np-button` before it disappears and before `login-button` appears.**  In this case, you trigger a `mouseleave` event on `np-button` rather than leaving from `login-button`, on which there is no event handler.

If you attach both events to both buttons, you will notice the problem disappears, or at least it seems to from my end.

With `.on()` this is written like this:

```
$("body").on('mouseenter', '.np-button, .login-button', function() {
    $('.np-button').hide();
    $('.login-button').show();
}).on('mouseleave', '.np-button, .login-button', function() {
    $('.np-button').show();
    $('.login-button').hide();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/sAQFN/

Answer (score 8):

There is very simple way to do this without using javascript. Just CSS. Of course if you want just make element visible or not.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="visible">
    <div class="hidden">Some text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
.visible:hover .hidden{
    display: block;
}
```

It helps to avoid situation, when `mouseleave` or `mouseout` are not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers I've seen solve the OP's problem, but not the general problem. For anyone facing this issue who can not use the CSS hover event, I've found that the DOM version of this JQuery event handler handles fast mouse movements more consistently.

```
document.getElementById("elementId").addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {
    {function to run}
});
document.getElementById("elementId").addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {
    {function to run}
});
```